# Rota com o caracter "."

Tags: slim

Pessoal preciso criar uma rota no qual um parâmetro dele seja um nome de arquivo com a extensão. Como eu crio desta ela? Ex.
http://localhost:8080/download/arquivo.pdf

Eu criei assim mas da erro por causa do ponto antes do PDF.

```
$app->get('/download/:arquivo', function($arquivo) use($app) {...});
```

Obrgado

Answer (score 0):

Lá na [documentação](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-placeholders) tem algumas formas de fazer isso.
Algumas:
/download/{arquivo}

Só mais uma coisa, qual erro você obtem? rota não encontrada? ou só não consegue ler a extensão?